# Pickling static method - Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, static-methods, pickle

I'm doing some multiprocessing in Python, using classes, and to do such thing I had to use this [approach](https://gist.github.com/fiatmoney/1086393):

```
def _pickle_method(method):
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    if func_name.startswith('__') and not func_name.endswith('__'): #deal with mangled names
        cls_name = cls.__name__.lstrip('_')
        func_name = '_' + cls_name + func_name
    print cls
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)


def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    for cls in cls.__mro__:
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)
```

The problem is 'cause I have some static methods that should parallelized too. But I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111106/cant-pickle-static-method-multiprocessing-python) that with this I can't pickle static methods. I'm wondering it there is a way to change this methods to do such thing, so I could pickle both non-static and static methods.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you need this approach? Are your class methods dynamically generated?

Comment: This was the only way I found to multiprocessing a class method.

Comment: Why not pass a regular function to the pool instead, and in that function call the methods?

Comment: But this is what I'm trying to do. Didn't understanding what you mean.

Comment: Instead of `pool.apply_async(ImageData.shepard_interpolation, args=[ImageData()])`, create a separate function `def apply_shepard_interpolation(img): img.shepard_interpolation()` and pass that to the pool with `pool.apply_async(apply_shepard_interpolation, args=[ImageData()])`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you were trying to do… but if you want to work with classes and `multiprocessing`, it's going to be ugly unless you jump outside the standard library.

If you use a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocesssing`, you can directly use classes and class methods in multiprocessing's `map` functions.  This is because `dill` is used instead of `pickle` or `cPickle`, and `dill` can serialize almost anything in python.

`pathos.multiprocessing` also provides an asynchronous map function… and it can `map` functions with multiple arguments (e.g. `map(math.pow, [1,2,3], [4,5,6])`)

See:
[What can multiprocessing and dill do together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984152/what-can-multiprocessing-and-dill-do-together)

and:
http://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2013/12/05/Parallelism-and-Serialization/

```
>>> from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
>>> 
>>> p = Pool(4)
>>> 
>>> def add(x,y):
...   return x+y
... 
>>> x = [0,1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6,7]
>>> 
>>> p.map(add, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> 
>>> class Test(object):
...   def plus(self, x, y): 
...     return x+y
... 
>>> t = Test()
>>> 
>>> p.map(Test.plus, [t]*4, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> 
>>> p.map(t.plus, x, y)
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Get the code here:
 https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos