# distribute jobs with python's multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, composition, python-multiprocessing

### Problem Description

I have some code I've just started trying to speed up in Python 3.5. I am trying to accomplish this with the `multiprocessing` module. Here is a minimum example to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Serially, the code is more straightforward. The `Momma_Serial` class has a list of `Baby` objects inside of it. Occasionally, we want to call the `Baby.evolve()` method on each of these. In practice, there are going to be a lot of these `Baby` objects (only 100 in this example). This was the original motivation for seeking parallelism.

What complicates this whole thing is that the top level of the program tells how this is done on each of the many `Baby` objects by passing a function `pass_this_func()`. This function is an argument to `Momma_Serial.evolve_all_elems()`, and is passed along to all of the little baby objects inside this momma object.

```
class Baby:
    def __init__(self, lol):
        self.lol = lol

    def evolve(self, f):
        self.lol = f(self.lol)

def pass_this_func(thing):
    return( 2 * thing )        

class Momma_Serial:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.my_list = [Baby(i) for i in range(num)]

    def evolve_all_elems(self, the_func):
        for baby in self.my_list:
            baby.evolve(the_func)


momma1 = Momma_Serial(100)
[baby.lol for baby in momma1.my_list]
momma1.evolve_all_elems(pass_this_func)
[baby.lol for baby in momma1.my_list]
```

This works as it should. But it's slow. Here's my attempt at re-writing the Momma class using the multiprocessing module.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class Momma_MP:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.my_list = [Baby(i) for i in range(num)]

    def evolve_all_elems(self, the_func):

        num_workers = 2            

        def f(my_obj):
            my_obj.evolve(the_func)

        with mp.Pool(num_workers) as pool:        
            pool.map(f, self.my_list)
```

Then I try to run it:

```
momma2 = Momma_MP(100)
[baby.lol for baby in momma2.my_list]
momma2.evolve_all_elems(pass_this_func) #error comes here
# [baby.lol for baby in momma2.my_list]
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Momma_MP.evolve_all_elems.<locals>.f'
```

An answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error) states "functions are only picklable if they are defined at the top-level of a module." This statement makes it seem like the only way to accomplish this is by defining a function outside of the `Momma_MP` class. But I really don't want to do that, because it would raise a lot more issues for my code.

### My Questions ##

(edited a bit)
Is there any workaround? Assume that I cannot define the mapped function outside of the class. Also assume `Momma()` is not being instantiated in the `__main__` top-level script environment. Also, I don't want to deviate too much from this program design, because I want all these Baby() instances being abstracted away; I don't want the places/programs that instantiate instances or interact with instances of `Momma()` having to worry or know about anything to do with the `Baby()` class. These extra restrictions make the problem slightly different from the situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-how-to-use-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class).

By the way, the following doesn't throw an error, but there might be some copying going on, because nothing happens to the constituent Baby objects.

```
def outside_f(obj):
    obj.evolve(pass_this_func)       

class Momma_MP:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.my_list = [Baby(i) for i in range(num)]

    def evolve_all_elems(self, the_func):
        num_workers = 2            

        with mp.Pool(num_workers) as pool:        
            pool.map(outside_f, self.my_list)        

momma2 = Momma_MP(100)
[baby.lol for baby in momma2.my_list]
momma2.evolve_all_elems(pass_this_func)
[baby.lol for baby in momma2.my_list] # no change here?
```

Comment: Also see [pickling class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-how-to-use-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111106/cant-pickle-static-method-multiprocessing-python , which has a solution of taking the global function and making it a static function within the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give an answer that isn't covered elsewhere that I could find (see my comments above).  I'm going to assume you have different kinds of Momma's that have different `f()` functions.

You could make a single function `evolver()`:

```
def evolver(baby):
   momma = baby.momma
   momma.evolve(baby)
```

You would need to assign `self.momma` in the `__init__()` of the `Baby`, passing the `Momma` instance to the `Baby`:

```
class Baby:
    def __init__(self, lol, momma):
        self.lol = lol
        self.momma = momma
```

Now you would derive from `Momma` to override the `evolve()` method to specialize the `evolve()` function.

So now when you call `pool.map(evolver, babies)`, it would pass the `baby` to `evolver()`, which would then ask the `momma` to `evolve()` the `baby`.

An answer I linked to above says you could also do the following as well:

```
class Momma:
    evolver = staticmethod(evolver)
```

...to put the global method into the class.

Comment: I'm going to keep looking at that thread you linked to. `pathos.multiprocessing` looks cool since I don't have to change much. I don't know if I want to use your first way, since it seems sort of roundabout. The staticmethod thing might work. I'll take another look at the link tomorrow morning. At the moment, I don't see how it will help since I thought the problem was `f` not being pickleable...not the function mapping/using said `f` being bound, or whatever.