# using multiprocessing.Pool on bound methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle, pool

I'm trying to use `multiprocessing.Pool` in my code but I got this exception:

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma) and it's [preferred solution recipe](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods#edit2155350)

my problem is that I don't know how to implement this solution in my code.

my code is something like that:

```
class G(class):
    def submit(self,data):
        cmd = self.createCommand(data)
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        # call for a short command

    def main(self):
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        while(True):
            data = self.GenerateData()
            self.pool.apply_async(self.Submit, args=(data,))
```

some notes:

- the main `while` should work for a long time (few days)
- I'm using `pool` for performance purposes, if you have a better solution I will be glad to here it

### update:

after using @unutbu solution I got the next exception:
`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed`

now , all the solutions I found were talking about `Queue.Queue` and `mp.Pool.map` but I'm not using those attributes so I can't figure it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: < http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726809/python-efficient-workaround-for-multiprocessing-a-function-that-is-a-data-membe >. Also, the current answer is also pretty much a duplicate of the same user's answer there.

Comment: @EMS it is very similar, and also the result of course, but the problem that it doesn't work, it gives the exception above.

Comment: do you really mean to have your class inherit from `class`???

Comment: also the same as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma?lq=1 with the same answer.

Comment: As of now as I tested on Linux, `Queue` and `Pipe` both accept bound methods, but not lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of Steven Bethard's solution to your situation:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import copy_reg
import types

def _pickle_method(method):
    """
    Author: Steven Bethard 
    http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods
    """
    func_name = method.im_func.__name__
    obj = method.im_self
    cls = method.im_class
    cls_name = ''
    if func_name.startswith('__') and not func_name.endswith('__'):
        cls_name = cls.__name__.lstrip('_')
    if cls_name:
        func_name = '_' + cls_name + func_name
    return _unpickle_method, (func_name, obj, cls)


def _unpickle_method(func_name, obj, cls):
    """
    Author: Steven Bethard
    http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods
    """
    for cls in cls.mro():
        try:
            func = cls.__dict__[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            break
    return func.__get__(obj, cls)

# This call to copy_reg.pickle allows you to pass methods as the first arg to
# mp.Pool methods. If you comment out this line, `pool.map(self.foo, ...)` results in
# PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup
# __builtin__.instancemethod failed

copy_reg.pickle(types.MethodType, _pickle_method, _unpickle_method)

class G(object):
    def submit(self, data):
        print('processing {}'.format(data))
        # cmd = self.createCommand(data)
        # subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
        # call for a short command
        time.sleep(2)

    def main(self):
        pool = mp.Pool()
        while True:
            data = (1, 2, 3)
            pool.apply_async(self.submit, args=(data,))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = G()
    g.main()
```

Comment: thanks! now I have another exception:`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed`

Comment: If you want to pickle a thread.lock you can pickle it with dill (instead of pickle).  Dill can also pickle bound methods.  However, if you want to use dill and multiprocessing, then you have to use pathos.multiprocessing (a fork of multiprocessing that gives better serialization).  See the link in my comment above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816958/cant-pickle-type-instancemethod-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-pool-ma?lq=1)