# Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, compilation

I know that there is a ["Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7"](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266) but is there, currently or planned, a Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4 or eve Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.x for that matter?  It would be supremely beneficial if I didn't have to install a different version of visual studio on my entire lab.

Comment: The version of the compiler should match, here is a table: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately to be able to use the extension modules provided by others you'll be forced to use the official compiler to compile Python.  These are:

- Visual Studio 2008 for Python 2.7.
  See: https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows
- Visual Studio 2010 for Python 3.4.
  See: https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows

Alternatively, you can use MinGw to compile extensions in a way that won't depend on others.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/install/#gnu-c-cygwin-MinGW or https://docs.python.org/3.4/install/#gnu-c-cygwin-mingw

This allows you to have one compiler to build your extensions for both versions of Python, Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Comment: For Python 2.7, you can also use the free [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44266) since you can no longer download the free version of VS 2008 that was once available.

Comment: The link in the last comment is dead.  We cannot download Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from Microsoft any longer.  kkocdko put it here for now: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1S67hq5hsWWW6SJgkaIQlupYugS2b9UiM

Answer (score 10):

For the different python versions:

```
Visual C++ |CPython
--------------------
14.0       |3.5
10.0       |3.3, 3.4
9.0        |2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2
```

Source: [Windows Compilers for py](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)

Also refer: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631048/2142994)

Answer (score 8):

[Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) suffices to build extensions for Python 3.5. It's free but a 6 GB download (overkill). On my computer it installed vcvarsall at  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat`

For Python 3.4 you'd need Visual Studio 2010. I don't think there's any free edition. See https://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/python_msvc.html

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I have Visual Studio Community 2015 and Python 3.5.1, but when trying to install numpy with pip I get the error that vcvarsall.bat cannot be located (Visual Studio Community 2015 only appears to have vcvars32.bat)

Comment: Hi. Try running the installer again, make sure you check `Visual C++` under programming languages.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33323172/vcvarsall-bat-needed-for-python-to-compile-missing-from-visual-studio-2015-v-1

Comment: Make sure your packages will work compiled against 2015.  MySQL's module, for example, will not work with 2015 and 3.5.1.

Comment: i have the same kind of problems. I have VS Community 2015 on Win8.1. looking at "About Microsoft Visual Studio" i see that Visual C++ 2015 is installed. However, no hint of any vsvarsall.bat file in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\` folder. I managed to install numpy (and tensorflow) via conda and pip with Python2.7 but not with Python3.5

Comment: You don't need to install Visual Studio 2015. Visual C++ Build Tools are enough. 

https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_Build_Tools_2015_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.29

Comment: I just don't understand why do I need to download 4GB to compile some python lib