# When trying to install with pip get "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, python-3.4

I'm using `Python 3.4`. I tried installing `Visual Studio 2010 Express` and then got the error:

```
ValueError: ['path']
```

I read that the reason is that express is for 32 bit and not 64, so I tried installing `Windows SDK 7.1`, but during the install it said

> Some components cannot be installed
>
> Some Windows SDK components require the RTM .NET Framework 4. Setup
>   detected a pre-release version of the .NET Framework 4. If you
>   continue with Setup, these components will not be installed. If you
>   want to install these components, click Cancel, then install the .NET
>   Framework 4 from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187668 and
>   then rerun Setup.

I have .NET Framework 4.5 installed.

What should I do?
I can't delete existing version I have, which are:
Visual studio 2011, 2012 for 64 bit
Visual studio 2011, 2012, 2014 for 32 bit

Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909330/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-3-4