# how to install mysql-python on windows 10

Tags: python, mysql, django, pip, mysql-python

I need to install mysqldb for python on windows 10, I tried the below way but I got same error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

pip install mysqlclinet, easy_instal mysql-python

Please help!

```html
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

    E:\Python\Django-PyCharm\DjangoPyCharmWeb>easy_install mysqlclient
Searching for mysqlclient
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/mysqlclient/
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.1
2.tar.gz#md5=dbf1716e2c01966afec0198d75ce7e69
Best match: mysqlclient 1.3.12
Processing mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\Hoshmand\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-4ln2fjka\mysqlclient-1.3.12\setup.cfg
Running mysqlclient-1.3.12\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-4ln2fjka\mysqlclien
t-1.3.12\egg-dist-tmp-aeu8iq_w
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

E:\Python\Django-PyCharm\DjangoPyCharmWeb>

    C:\Users\me\Downloads\mysqlclient-1.3.12>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.6
copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\REFRESH.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.6
creating build\temp.win32-3.6\Release
cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,3,12,'final',0) -D__version__=1.3.12 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" -IC:\Python\Python36\include -IC:\Python\Python36\include /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [Maybe this will help] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059732/error-command-cl-exe-failed-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

C++ libraries not found.
Check link:https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/145

Comment: Can you tell  libraries name that I need to install?

Comment: Had to install C++ compilers. Can you check link?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip` instead of `easy_install`. That way it should install the `wheel` instead of building from source.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I used pip but there is same error

Comment: Please copy and paste the output from when you tried pip. Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: E:\Python\Django-PyCharm\DjangoPyCharmWeb>pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient 
    error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory

Comment: here you are I used python 3.6

Comment: I'm surprised it's not using the wheel. What if you do `pip install --no-cache-dir mysqlclient`?

Comment: Sir I tried this (pip install --no-cache-dir mysqlclient) also but same error

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you manage to get it to work