# 'pip install duckling' giving issue

Tags: rasa-nlu

I want to install duckling to work on Rasa nlu training but it is giving issue as mentioned in below image please help me to fix this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA3Ie.png)

Answer (score 2):

As a suitable alternative would you consider running Rasa NLU in docker. The rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-full docker image includes duckling. If you wanted to get started with it and you have docker installed you should be able to just run

```
docker run rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-full
```

Then you can interact with Rasa over it's HTTP API https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu#example-use

The docker file allow's more complicated setups like over writing the default config file and saving the logs/models/etc to a persistent disk

https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu#advanced-docker

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue! This is basically the issue of jpype modules. 
You need to first install the jpype in your environment. 
you can use `conda install -c conda-forge jpype1`
For installing the jpype you can also refer to
[official link for jpype installation](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

On successful installation of jpype duckiling can be installed using

```
pip install duckling -U
```

I hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

You should download VC+ compiler for windows and then try the pip install.

You can download it here
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/9/6/796EF2E4-801B-4FC4-AB28-B59FBF6D907B/VCForPython27.msi

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Python 3.6 and I installed Visual C++ 14.0, still am facing this issue. Still I need to install what you suggested or does this issue require any other configurations.

Comment: For python 3 I think its not going to be easy. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909330/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-3-4`. If you feel there is a lot to do for this setup I would say you should look for `VM/Docker with py3 image`  which would do better job.