# Installing twisted on Windows 10 64 bit under python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, windows-10, twisted

Does anyone know how to do this. I have googled and the best that I could come up with was to do:

pip install autobahn[twisted]

when I do that I get this error in the command window

```
C:\Users\<User Name>\Desktop>pip install autobahn[twisted]
Collecting autobahn[twisted]
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading autobahn-18.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (283kB)
    100% |################################| 286kB 1.0MB/s
Collecting txaio>=2.7.0 (from autobahn[twisted])
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I have no idea how to fix the error

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't a programming question.  Instead, it's a question about how to use a package mangement tool, "pip" (and possibly a report of a bug in that software).

Comment: Upon actually parsing the traceback, seems like the error occurs when trying to make a request to some url (`self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)`)

Answer (score -1):

Go to [University of California Irvine's Unofficial Windows Binary for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted) and download the Twisted wheel file. This is the easy way. The hard way requires a compiler (comes packaged in Windows Built Tools) to be installed.

**PLEASE NOTE!!!!** For anyone stumbling onto this thread, only the latest package is available for download (usually) through the University of California Irvine site, so it would be wise to **SAVE** the binaries for future use. This is very useful if a specific version is required. Otherwise the specific compiler needs to used to compile packages.

## References

- [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909330/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-3-4)
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Comment: This doesn't really seem like the answer to this question.  The question is basically "pip has this error when downloading a package" and the answer is "manually go to this semi-mirror and manually get the package yourself".  That may be a useful workaround but it's not an *answer*.  What's going on with pip?

Comment: That's a good point. I basically assumed a bit much and based on what I dealt with in a Windows env, I figured he just needed install twisted by any means. I don't have a Windows machine to test these days :(

Comment: Yea.  It's good _support_ but that's a bit different from "good SO content" I think.

Comment: Ok I hate to sound dumb. But what do you do after you download the .whl file. I am just gettting back into python programming. I stopped in the mid 2005s. Back then you downloaded a .zip or .arc or MAYBE a .gz.

Comment: You should be able to something like this `python -m pip install twisted.whl` or just double click it