# Little help installing c++ and Python on server

Tags: python, c++, server

I need to install python 2.7 and c++ on a server, 2.7 is end of life so i am going to install 3.9

I can find the c++ compiler for python 2.7 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 but cannot find it for python 3.9

If this is the case, can someone direct me to the best version of c++ that will play nicely with python 3.9?

I am a complete noob at these things, may have missed some things out.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909330/microsoft-visual-c-compiler-for-python-3-4)

Comment: @andI'msureI'mmissingsome almost, although i cannot find reference to python 3.9, so is it suggesting that i would not use the c++ compiler but will need visual studios?

Comment: Please clarify "installing c++".  There are a plethora of C++ compilers, such as GNU and IAR to name a few.  Do you mean to install a compiler or an application?

Comment: Please clarify "the best version of c++".  Are you talking about C++11, C++14, C++20?